# Count the number of rows do not match certain condition in other table

Tags: mysql

**students_records**

```
+----+-----+-----+ 
| Sr | SRN | ARN |
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  | ge  | aj  |
| 2  | ge  | bd  |
+----+-----+-----+
```

**answer**

```
+----+-----+-----+
| Sr | SRN | ARN |
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  | ge  | aj  |
| 2  | ge  | aj  |
| 3  | ge  | ne  |
| 4  | ge  | bd  |
+----+-----+-----+
```

I need to  count the number of `rows` in table `answer` whose `ARN value of answer is not equal (!=) to any ARN value of students_records`.

For the above database, the count will be **1** as **a2** in answers is not in any row of ARN of students_records.

Comment: your code makes no sense, it selects just the first record from students_records. you need a query with JOIN to get your result

Comment: @YourCommonSense How to JOIN the queries..?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I will be thankful if I get the edits with my codes...

Comment: It will be easier to learn JOIN for me if it is edited in my codes, as I will have 2 different codes to understand then... So, I request you @YourCommonSense to edit it in my codes. Thanks.

Comment: Well may be. but I am not your teacher.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, I know but you are senior from me, and only one senior can help more than the teacher as he/she has experiences...

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am still waiting for the answer

Comment: It's good for you. Someday it will come

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning, here is a working query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM answer AS a
LEFT JOIN student_records AS s ON a.Sr = s.Sr
WHERE s.Sr IS NULL
```

Explanation:

- some other databases have a keyword EXCEPT, others have MINUS, that does provide the results from one set that are not in another set.  MySQL does not.
- To do something similar, you do a LEFT JOIN and filter on the empty lines.
- Lets build the query:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM answer AS a
  LEFT JOIN student_records AS s ON a.Sr = s.Sr
  ```

  You will get this:

  ```
  Sr   SRN   ARN   Sr    SRN   ARN
  1    s1    a1    1     s1    a1
  2    s1    a2    2     s1    a3
  3    s1    a3    null  null  null
  ```

  Then add the WHERE line, you get this:

  ```
  Sr   SRN   ARN   Sr    SRN   ARN
  3    s1    a3    null  null  null
  ```

  And finally, change the SELECT to COUNT(*), you get 1.

By the way, when I started working on your question, **I had NO CLUE how to do this**.  Then google helped, and I found this: http://www.gokhanatil.com/2010/10/minus-and-intersect-in-mysql.html

Research if your friend!

Comment: hmmm seems it will work, thanks a lot... but there is a small mistake by me... please see my question again especially the database...

Comment: Ya, you changed the data in the tables, but now your description of the problem does not work anymore (it still says 1 because of a2 ...).  Adapt the query as required, if required.  If the question changed significantly, accept this answer and start a new one, do not edit an old question.  With the new data I think the response should be 2?

Comment: Will the above code mentioned by you give me the results as I want..?I.e 1

Comment: Why don't you run it and see?